# Installing gem without the internet availability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems

Yesterday I tried to install `rspec` gem on a system which was not connected to internet, so this is what I did-

I downloaded the gem for rspec using the command `gem install rspec` and on command prompt its showing 5 gem inside the package - (system with internet conn)

diff-lcs-1.1.3, rspec-2.12.0, rspec-core-2.12.2, rspec-expectations-2.12.1, rspec-mocks-2.12.2

I copied the 5 folders from this location -

```
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems
```

and pasted in the same path9system without internet connection),

when I updated the gem file with `gem 'rspec'` (computer without the internet connection) and restarted the server its still showing error.

I need to know if there is something else that updated during the installation which i am missing?

What other parts I need to add to make this rspec working on a computer without having internet connection.

PS- `New to rails :)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To cache the gems execute `bundle cache` and it will save all the gem in `vendor/cache` directory.

When you you execute `bundle install`, it will use the cached gems.

Comment: and where do i find this folder (vendor/cache) is it same ? myproject\vendor\  ?

Comment: thanks got your point ..checked it ..its creating a cache folder under vendor ..thanks :) I will test it on comp without the internet conn and if everything goes fine..I will accept it as an answer for sure :)