# Is there a way to add Rubies in RVM without the internet?

Tags: ruby, installation, rvm

I work in the managed server and it does not have internet access, and I need to install some rubies to RVM but whenever I use rvm install , it tries to access the internet for it ( which obviously fails because of the firewall)

Is there a way to circumvent this problem without modifying the source and rebuilding? I have the rubies with me locally.

Thanks for any help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing gem without the internet availability](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597026/installing-gem-without-the-internet-availability)

Comment: That question is rails-specific, what I'm looking for is RVM specific. As in, how do I add different version of ruby to it without it going to look for them on the internet

Comment: That question works with or without rails as long as your have bundler. You can also download the gem files and install them from the files.

Comment: There is also some instructions at  [RVM in offline mode](https://rvm.io/rvm/offline)

Comment: possible duplicate of [install RVM offline completely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459149/install-rvm-offline-completely)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RVM has instructions for offline installation https://rvm.io/rvm/offline/